# Errors with NIntegrate: NIntegrate::ncvb and NIntegrate::slwcon

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, singularity, error-tracking

[image]

The image shows the array (W) I'm trying to integrate. 
It gives the following errors:
1. NIntegrate::ncvb
2. NIntegrate::slwcon

I tried excluding the singularity points; adjusting the accuracy goal, working precision, min recursion and max recursion but nothing seems to eliminate the errors.

I'm using Mathematica 11.1. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful